# Alien visits Earth with flying small parasites

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I only remember one scene from this movie from the 80s. A humanoid alien is in a swamplike area on Earth and throws some kind of a detachment (a sub-creature from himself?). This small detachment (about the size of a human palm) flies like some kind of a bio-saucer and attacks a human. The human is inside a car, so this flying little thing thumps against the windshield. Now it looks like a wiggling suction cup, it's eager to get at the human. I suppose it's some kind of a body snatcher storyline from here(?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, browsing through the Wikipedia page [List of films featuring extraterrestrials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_extraterrestrials), I found it: [Without Warning (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081764/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

Synopsis:
A young man and his father go hunting in a mountain area with forests somewhere in the American Midwest only to find themselves being hunted by alien creatures.

[image]

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It is impossible to accept one's own answer. I hope you don't mean that I'm after the (for me) useless reputation points that sites like these have to offer... I just got upset that nobody answered within an hour and took matters in my own hand :-) As to the plot summary, isn't that kind of a spoiler for others? I'm not sure if it's encouraged to include it, maybe it is?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Oh, okay. Sorry for jumping to conclusions. I guess there is a mechanism to avoid self answer abuse anyway (if there is such a thing at all). I'm getting used to asking questions so difficult that I have to keep answering them myself :-P Anyway, the knowledge base is growing and that's the point.

Comment: @stevie- I don't think it gives you any points for it. But yeah, better that you answer your own question and save people the time of having to do their own when you already know. Good answer.